# Update entire object with value binding on select with knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, mapping, observable

I have a select dropdown menu which shows a list of objects, with the `name` property being the text displayed, the `id` property being the value each option is bound to, and a `value: user.id` binding which is from a separate property on another object.

```
<td data-bind=""><select data-bind="options: peopleResponsible, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: user.id"></select></td>
```

When I select a new person object from the dropdown list, only the `id` on the `user` is being updated. All of the other properties (name, username, age, etc) are not being updated.

What I need for it to do is when a new `peopleResponsible` option is selected, I want it to copy across *all* of the properties from that object to the `user` object.

I have a suspicion that at the moment it currently does not work because the `user` object itself is not observable, only its properties are. Here is how my data is being mapped:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(taskOutlines, {}, mappedTaskOutlines);
```

Where a `TaskOutline` contains many `Tasks`, and each `Task` contains a single `User`.

Any ideas?

Comment: try setting up a fiddle it will be easy to fix it . cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
var vm = {
  peopleResponsible: ko.observableArray([{
    id: ko.observable(1),
    name: ko.observable("p1")
  }, {
    id: ko.observable(2),
    name: ko.observable("p2")
  }, {
    id: ko.observable(3),
    name: ko.observable("p3")
  }]),
  selectedUser: ko.observable()
}

vm.selectedUser(vm.peopleResponsible()[1]); // pre select a user

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>



<select data-bind="options: peopleResponsible, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedUser"></select>
<div data-bind="with: selectedUser">
  <p>Id:
    <label data-bind="text: id"></label>
  </p>
  <p>Name:
    <label data-bind="text: name"></label>
  </p>
</div>
```

When a selection is made that selection will be a reference to the arbitrary object in the observable array, properties and all. This selected object will then be placed in "selectedUser" observable.

So in short, removing the "optionsValue" binding will bind the entire object instead of the id property.

Comment: Alright, thanks, this does appear to be binding the entire `selectedUser` object, but it's not binding the correct objects initially (i.e. when I a preset user already selected), how can I fix that?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a demonstration. This demo also shows you how to have a user preselected.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` binding only sets one observable. Not knowing how things are used, it's hard to say what you should do to get the result you want. One possibility is to make a function that does the copying and `subscribe` to the `user.id`.